# selecting prices from select options with JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, select

I have a bunch of select fields in a form.  Some of the options in the select fields have a price.  The price is always in the format `<option>text (+£9.99)</option>` although obviously the price can vary. I am looking to grab all of the prices from options if one of the selects is changed.  I only want prices from options that are selected at the time of the change though.

Using the JQuery `.change()` method is fine but I am struggling to understand how to use the `.match` method to return the numeric value from the options and how to get only selected options.  I figure the regex would be `'/\(\+£([0-9\.]+)\)/'`.

```
$("select").live('change',function () {
  var price = 0;
  $("select option:selected").live('each',function () {
    price += $(this).text().match('/\(\+£([0-9\.]+)\)/');
  });
  alert (price);
})
```

I am using live because the form is loaded via ajax depending on another form on the page.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Luke

EDIT: I have tried `$(this).val().match` instead of the `.text` method.

EDIT 2: I cannot change the value of the option because it corresponds to the id of the option in the database. (refering to Dennis's answer below)

UPDATE:
In order to use the correct answer below with symfony I had to add a custom widget:

```
class myWidgetFormSelect extends sfWidgetFormSelect {

  /**
   * Returns an array of option tags for the given choices
   *
   * @param  string $value    The selected value
   * @param  array  $choices  An array of choices and attributes array key "content" denotes text
   * to be entered in option, all other keys become attributes
   *
   * @return array  An array of option tags
   */
  protected function getOptionsForSelect($value, $choices) {
    $mainAttributes = $this->attributes;
    $this->attributes = array();

    if (!is_array($value)) {
      $value = array($value);
    }

    $value = array_map('strval', array_values($value));
    $value_set = array_flip($value);

    $options = array();
    foreach ($choices as $key => $option) {
      $attributes = array('value' => self::escapeOnce($key));
      if (!is_array($option))
        $content = $option;
      else {
        foreach ($option as $name => $val) {
          if ($name == 'content')
            $content = $val;
          else
            $attributes[$name] = $val;
        }
      }
      if (isset($value_set[strval($key)])) {
        $attributes['selected'] = 'selected';
      }

      $options[] = $this->renderContentTag('option', self::escapeOnce(isset($content) ? $content : ''), $attributes);
    }

    $this->attributes = $mainAttributes;

    return $options;
  }

}
```

This class allows the choices array to be an array and have multiple attributes using a call like:

```
new myWidgetFormSelect(array(
  'choices' => array(
    '1' /* <- the id of the option */ => array(
      'content' => 'text (+£9.99)',
      'data-price' => '9.99'
    )
  )
))
```

Where the above would create a select field with the option:

```
<option value="1" data-price="9.99">text (+£9.99)</option>
```

I hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you structure your select list like so, with `data-price` attributes on each option:

```
<select>
    <option data-price="9.99">text (+£9.99)</option>
    <option data-price="1.99">text (+£1.99)</option>
</select>
```

then you can access the price value with `$('select option:selected').data('price')`. See this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z8Ft/

therefore your problem becomes much much simpler:

```
$("select").live('change',function () {
  var price = 0;
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
    price += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
  });
  alert (price);
})
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/yqTAB/

And since you mentioned symfony, I did a bit of a search and found this link: http://blog.sznapka.pl/symfony-sfwidgetformselect-with-disabled-options/ It describes adding an attribute (disabled in that case) to an option. You could use the same method to add these data attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jamiec, is there anything wrong with using the `.split(':')` method and using `value="id:price"` in your opinion as that would be far simpler for me?

Comment: @Luke - I think, although it works, its not a very 'clean' solution. But hey, sometimes you make that sacrifice for ease of development.

Comment: Thank you for this, with your dig about "not a very 'clean' solution" I decided to build a clean solution and use your jquery.  If your interested I updated my question with the code to create the attributes in the symfony form select options.

Answer (score 1):

You can structure your options like this:

```
<option value="9.99">text (+£9.99)</option>
```

That way you just need to call `$(this).val()`.  Make sure you parseInt or parseFloat otherwise you will end up concatenating strings.

---

Another issue with your code:

```
$("select option:selected").live('each',function () {
```

should be

```
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
```

As each is a function, not an event type

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for the answer, I didn't mention in the question but the value is the id of the option as each option is from the database and multiple option could have the same price.  Thanks again

Comment: putting the raw price in the value is defintely a better idea than trying to parse them out the text. +1.

Comment: @Luke - in that case use data-* attributes like `data-price="9.99"`

Comment: @Jamiec - do you know how to add data-* attributes to options when they are generated by symfony 1.4 forms?

Comment: @Luke - no idea. But if it is producing HTML and doesn't give you fine control over the generated HTML then ditch it fast.

Comment: Dennis - +1 because the each was breaking, thanks.  @Jamiec - unfortunately dropping symfony forms is not a great idea when using the symfony framework.  Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: @Luke - [this link](http://blog.sznapka.pl/symfony-sfwidgetformselect-with-disabled-options/) describes a way to add the disabled attribute to an option with symfony, you could use the same method to add the attribute I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

Match function will return a array of things. You should index it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$("select").live('change',function () {
  alert ($(this).val().match('£([0-9.]+)')[1]);
});
```